# Реализация flask_message в моделях или как в **method вызвать родительский класс?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть модель, в ней реализован статический метод **create()**, внутри которого обрабатывается исключение и flash.

Возможно это не лучшая идея, реализовывать такого рода обратную связь через модели, но мне эта идея понравилась. Т.к. при небольшой корректировке она легко масштабируется.

Есть один нюанс. Я хочу реализовать эти методы в модели **Base** , но для этого, в **@staticmethod** нужно передать класс (в данном случае **Contact**), для вызовы экземпляра.

Пробовал вместо @staticmethod использовать @classmethod, и внутри функции использовать cls.**name_**, но таким образом я получаю строку с названием, а не сам класс.

Есть идеи ?

```
class Contact(Base):

    first_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    position = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(EmailType, nullable=False, info={"label": "Email"})
    phone_mobile = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    phone_work = db.Column(db.String(50))
    phone_fax = db.Column(db.String(50))
    phone_other = db.Column(db.String(50))

    created_by = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False) 
    org_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organisation.id'), nullable=False, info={"label": "Organisation"})
    activities = db.relationship('Activity', backref='contact')


    @staticmethod
    def create(**kwargs):
        c = Contact(**kwargs)
        db.session.add(c)
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            flash((c.__tablename__).capitalize() + u' created successfully!', 'success')
        except IntegrityError:
            db.session.rollback()
            flash((c.__tablename__).capitalize() + u' created failed!', 'error')
        return c

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ларчик просто открывался.

```
@classmethod
def create(cls,**kwargs):
    c = cls(**kwargs)
    db.session.add(c)
    try:
        db.session.commit()
        flash((c.__tablename__).capitalize() + u' created successfully!', 'success')
    except IntegrityError:
        db.session.rollback()
        flash((c.__tablename__).capitalize() + u' created failed!', 'error')        
    return c
```